# How to solve error : " Not sure how to handle insert method's return type" in implement room with RX java

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, android-room

**This is my error after that i run the sample project that i developed with `Room` and `RX java` occur :**

```
e: /home/milad/workspace/android/WalletMVVM/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/example/walletmvvm/data/dao/CurrencyDao.java:15: error: Not sure how to handle insert method's return type.
    public abstract io.reactivex.Single<com.example.walletmvvm.data.model.CurrencyModel> insert(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
```

I searched a lot but i did not find anything.

I could implement `Retrofit` with `RX java` and use it and i could run the `Room` Query in other thread with `RX java` but i could not set `observer` and `subscribe` a `observable` with `RX java` yet.

Everything sounds good

This is my `Dao` :

```
@Dao
interface CurrencyDao {

        @Query("SELECT * FROM ${DbConstants.TABLE_CURRENCY} ORDER BY ${DbConstants.NAME_CURRENCY_MODEL} ASC")
        fun getCurrencyList(): Observable<List<CurrencyModel>>

        @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
        fun insert(currencyModel: CurrencyModel): Single<CurrencyModel>
    }
```

This is my `repository` :

```
companion object {

    // For Singleton instantiation
    @Volatile
    private var instance: CurrencyRepository? = null

    fun getInstance(currencyDao: CurrencyDao) =
        instance ?: synchronized(this) {
            instance ?: CurrencyRepository(currencyDao).also { instance = it }
        }
}

fun getCurrencyList(): Observable<List<CurrencyModel>>? {

    return currencyDao.getCurrencyList()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

}
```

This is my `fragment` that me `observer` the data :

```
private fun initObservers() {
    val getCurrencyListObserver = currencyViewModel.getCurrencyLists()
    getCurrencyListObserver?.subscribeWith(getCurrenciesFromDatabase())
}

private fun getCurrenciesFromDatabase() : Observer<List<CurrencyModel>> {


    return object : Observer<List<CurrencyModel>> {
        override fun onComplete() {

        }

        override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {

        }

        override fun onNext(t: List<CurrencyModel>) {

            t.let {

                showResult(it.size.toString() + " items")
                setRecyclerData(it)
                binding.listSize = it.size
            }
        }

        override fun onError(e: Throwable) {

        }
    }
}
```

**For implement this i study [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components) in medium and study [this](https://codinginfinite.com/android-room-persistent-rxjava/)**

**I see sample code about Kotlin in [googlesamples/android-architecture-components](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components) but they dont use observer**

---

Update :

because after that i remove `single` i cant use :

```
currencyDao.insert(currency)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe()
```

And  `currencyDao.insert(currency)` cant access to `.subscribeOn()` and other

---

Update :

i solved it when i changed the return type to `Long` type but i faced to new `error`

```
 @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(currencyModel: CurrencyModel): Single<Long>
```

And new error is :

```
e: /home/milad/workspace/android/WalletMVVM/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/example/walletmvvm/data/dao/CurrencyDao.java:11: error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (java.lang.Object).
    public abstract io.reactivex.Observable<java.lang.Object> getCurrencyList();
```

---

Update :

I changed the `insert` return type to `Completable` and it fixed

Comment: why does your insert return a `Single<CurrencyModel>`?

Comment: @Blackbelt , i changed it to Maybe and Observable but i faced with that error again!!

Comment: why do you need to return something ?

Comment: @Blackbelt , i update my question for reason that i want insert has return , but i solved it when i changed the return type to Long type but i faced to new error

Comment: you could use `Single.fromCallable` and make insert return nothing?

Comment: @Blackbelt , thank you i solved that but i have new problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your:

```
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(currencyModel: CurrencyModel): Single<CurrencyModel>
```

Should return a `Completable` not a `Single`

```
        @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
        fun insert(currencyModel: CurrencyModel): Completable
```

That's because there is no need to return anything when your operation is done. It just enters the `onComplete` block on the background.

Comment: return a `Completable` not a `Single`

Comment: Yes thank you but it solve my first problem i updated my question and i have new error

Comment: I don't see the `Completable` keyword on your update